# Whats is expiration time of access token received from Pinterest Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, sdk, access-token, pinterest

I've seen Pinterest access token retrieved using authorization code flow have no expiration. 
But i don't know if one received from Pinterest Javascript SDK also does not expire. Their token debugger does not show expiration time...

Comment: This is not the right place to ask those kind of question

Comment: @NejiSoltani If my question started with "Where should i ask ..." then your comment would be helpful...

Comment: and this is why you got plenty of answers (....)

Comment: @NejiSoltani Next time i'll ask some easy JS question so i can get many answers. Thanks for clarifying purpose of this site to me.

Comment: You're just wrong I didn't ask mean that you just have to ask a well explained question

Comment: So please read  [that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
All tokens, including those generated with our Javascript SDK are valid for the
lifetime of the current password of the user they were created for. If the user the
token belongs to updates their password, the token will no longer be valid and will
need to be recreated.
```

If anyone ever needs this... Received this info from Pinterest tech support.